# How to design an RNN to treat all training set as a time series in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a classification problem, where we have a pairwise input,

```
X1 = Input(shape=(input_size,), name='input_1')
X2 = Input(shape=(input_size,), name='input_2')
```

and the expected output is binary.

To solve this problem, I first design an `encoder` which takes these pairwise inputs and encode them with the shape of `(encoder_size, 2)`. Next, I want to design an RNN, where can treat the training set as a time series. In other words, I will feed `(X1, X2)` first, and feed `(X1, X3)` and so on. The reason is the former input may contain some global information need to memorize, which might be helpful to do the prediction for the later input.

For each input pair, I expect to see a binary prediction result. And the model keeps the memory of it and do a prediction for the next input pair.

I attach the code below, but I am not sure whether it can work like what I describe or not.

```
encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, input_shape=(input_size,)))
encoder.add(Dense(encoder_size, activation='relu'))
encoder.add(Reshape((-1,1)))

encoded_1 = encoder(X1)
encoded_2 = encoder(X2)
merged = concatenate([encoded_1, encoded_2])

# RNN model           
comparer = Sequential()
comparer.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(encoder_size,2), return_sequences=False))     
comparer.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
comparer.add(Dense(1))
comparer.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

Y = comparer(merged)
model = Model(inputs=[X1, X2], outputs=Y)
```

If not, what is the correct way? If yes, what is the way to treat the `(encoder_size, 2)` as the time series instead of the whole training set?